# How to refactor the similar methods into reusable common method?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, ecmascript-6

I have these 3 method that are very identical with one another. The only difference is that they have different keys to get the corresponding data. Can someone tell me how I can best reformat this into just one method instead of having 3 similar methods?

```
export function getPayloadObject(action) {
  let result = action.payload.map(data => {
    return {
      name: data['DSTR_NR'].value,
      value: data['Desc'].value
    }
  }, [])
  return result;
}

export function getPayloadObject2(action) {
  let result = action.payload.map(data => {
    return {
      name: data['PROCESS_NM'].value,
      value: data['PROCESS_ID'].value
    }
  }, [])
  return result;
}

export function getPayloadObject3(action) {
  let result = action.payload.map(data => {
    return {
      name: data['CD_DESC'].value,
      value: data['SUBQUEUE_CD'].value
    }
  }, [])
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only part changing here are the name and value keys. we can get these two as function parameters and use it within the function to retrieve name and value.

```
export function getPayloadObject(action, nameKey, valueKey) {
  let result = action.payload.map(data => {
    return {
      name: data[nameKey].value,
      value: data[valueKey].value
    }
  }, [])
  return result;
}
```

and use it like:

```
getPayloadObject(action, 'DSTR_NR', 'Desc');
getPayloadObject(action, 'PROCESS_NM', 'PROCESS_ID');
getPayloadObject(action, 'CD_DESC', 'SUBQUEUE_CD');
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try:

```
export function getPayloadObject(action, name, value) {
  let result = action.payload.map(data => {
    return {
      name: data[name].value,
      value: data[value].value
    }
  }, [])
  return result;
}
```